# DNS issues on Ubuntu 12.04 with OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, dns, openvpn

I followed this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN) to setup openvpn on my home network.

I accidentally downloaded ubuntu 12.10 at first and without noticing, I went ahead and followed the guide...

Then I did some stuff from [here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html):
push "redirect-gateway def1"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

to enable browsing.

OpenVPN was fully function.

By that I mean, I was able to remote in (access internal services) and mask my IP when browsing from the outside.

Then I realized that I wanted ubuntu 12.04 so I followed the same process on a new install.

Now the problem is that the DNS does not resolve.

I noticed that downloading openvpn downloaded resolvconf which I uninstalled and attempted to go about this manually.

Here is some stuff from my system:

openvpn server.conf:

```
mode server
tls-server

local 192.168.1.101 ## ip/hostname of server
port 80 ## default openvpn port
proto udp

#bridging directive
dev tap0 ## If you need multiple tap devices, add them here
up "/etc/openvpn/up.sh br0 tap0 1500"
down "/etc/openvpn/down.sh br0 tap0"

persist-key
persist-tun

#certificates and encryption
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh1024.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
comp-lzo

#DHCP Information
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
server-bridge 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.110
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"


#push "dhcp-option DOMAIN yourdomain.com"
#push "redirect-gateway local def1"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
#push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"


max-clients 10 ## set this to the max number of clients that should be connected at a time

#log and security
user nobody
group nogroup
keepalive 10 120
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
root@ironman:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces 
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
#auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
#############OPEN VPN SETUP###############
## This is the network bridge declaration

## Start these interfaces on boot
auto lo br0

iface lo inet loopback

iface br0 inet static 
  address 192.168.1.101 
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  bridge_ports eth0
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
iface eth0 inet manual
  up ip link set $IFACE up promisc on
  down ip link set $IFACE down promisc off
  nameserver 8.8.8.8

root@ironman:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.1.1


root@ironman:~# ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.239.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from nuq05s01-in-f4.1e100.net (74.125.239.100): icmp_req=1 ttl=55 time=22.6 ms
64 bytes from nuq05s01-in-f4.1e100.net (74.125.239.100): icmp_req=2 ttl=55 time=21.7 ms
64 bytes from nuq05s01-in-f4.1e100.net (74.125.239.100): icmp_req=3 ttl=55 time=22.8 ms
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you ping raw IPs? I had a similar problem and it turned out DNS was find, but my firewall was blocking everything. After I disabled that and/or added a rule, OpenVPN worked.

Answer (score 32):

This works for me: http://www.softwarepassion.com/solving-dns-problems-with-openvpn-on-ubuntu-box/

The important step is adding following three lines into your client openvpn config file:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Also ensure the `resolvconf` package is installed on the client as this script depends on it.

It works with openvpn client service or command (`sudo openvpn youropenvpn.conf`).

However, the Ubuntu Network Manager doesn't work for this configuration. It's an issue so far: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1211110

Comment: I wish there was a way to give you 1K score for this answer which seems to be missing everywhere!

Answer (score 1):

When you re-installed 12.04 did you forget this step?

> echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Source: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/88-1xhowto.html