# 16.04 Xubuntu - OpenVPN losing DNS after a couple of minutes

Tags: vpn, dns, openvpn

Stock install of Xubuntu 16.04.

Followed [this guide](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/18003/openvpn-step-by-step-setups-for-various-debian-based-linux-oss-with-videos-ubuntu-mint-debian/p1%C2%A0) to install OpenVPN for Network Manager, and to download the certs and opvn files for PIA VPN.

I am able to add the opvn connection and connect successfully, and everything works for about 2 minutes.

Then I lose internet and I am unable to ping anything - no google.com, no yahoo, nothing.

As soon as I disconnect, my internet is back.

This is being done via wireless to my router.

Any ideas?

Comment: So I initiate the VPN from the command line via sudo, and it appears that the errors coorelated with the drop in connectivity: http://pastebin.com/hMNFXA1J

Comment: Actually it's happening even without the replay errors.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but an answer may serve people like me, who get here via a fourty minute google session.

Starting with a small disclaimer: I'm on a Raspberry Pi 3 with a Raspbian (Debian) Jessie image.

My system showed same symptoms like OP had (vpn going good, and after a few minutes suddenly no more browsing or ping to addresses like www.google.com). Additionally I found that I was still able to ping ip-addresses (like 8.8.8.8). This fits well with the claimed DNS issue.

I found the solution here at askubuntu SE: [using the resolvconf package and amending the ovpn-client-file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359299/dns-issues-on-ubuntu-12-04-with-openvpn).